# we need to show $Re(p)=0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Could any one tell me how to solve this one?

$p\in\mathbb{C}$,consider the diff equ $$u''-p^2u=0$$, if every solution of the diff equ satisfies $$\sup_{T>0}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T} |u(t)| dt<\infty$$ Then we need to show $Re(p)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

First assume $p \neq 0$. (What can you say about the differential equation in this case? What are the solutions like?) Write $\tilde{p} = -ip$, then you have $u'' + \tilde{p}^2u = 0$. The formal solutions to this are $u(t) = A\exp(i\tilde{p}t) + B\exp(-i\tilde{p}t) = A\exp(pt)+B\exp(-pt)$. What can you say about the long term behavior of this function at $\pm\infty$ if $Re(p) \neq 0$? (Answering this question effectively solves your problem.)